# Up Button - getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true) - closes app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I've tried to make a "return" button for my app, or as Google call it, Up Button for Low-level Activities.

I wrote everything properly:
in My XML I put the meta-data and the parent activity (Example from Google, I modified the text to my app in my files)

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
```

in My class I put the next line:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

but when I click this up button, the app closes, then opened again from the main screen.

I want it to return to the main screen without closing (finishing) the app.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show more code? What are you doing on OnOptionItemSelected() ?

Comment: @joao2fast4u nothing related to that thing, because Google didn't so.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#UpNav

Comment: For what API version are you testing your code?

Comment: Can you show the Manifest file, please?

Comment: @joao2fast4u I'm testing on KitKat (API 19), and as i said, I declared the right things on my manifest.
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />

Comment: You have two Activities? Or just MainActivity?

Comment: More than one activity. I put the class line only at the "Second" activity.

Comment: Do both of your Activities extend ActionBarActivity?

Comment: There must be something you are doing wrong. I just tried that approach and it works. You have to show more from your Manifest.xml file, Edit your question ,please.

Comment: @joao2fast4u What have you done precisely?

Comment: I will write an answer explaining exactly what I did to accomplish what your are trying to do.

Comment: @joao2fast4u ok, waiting.

Comment: See my answer. If it helps you, please accept it/upvote it.

Comment: @joao2fast4u I commented it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#UpNav),

> When running on Android 4.1 (API level 16) or higher, or when using ActionBarActivity from the Support Library, performing Up navigation simply requires that you declare the parent activity in the manifest file and enable the Up button for the action bar.

So, I have two `Activities`: FirstActivity, which is my launcher and parent `Activity` and SecondActivity, which is my child `Activity`.

My FirstActivity code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main_activity);

    Button secondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondButton);

    secondButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));

        }
    });

}

}
```

My SecondActivity code:

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_place_activity);

    //enable the ActionBar behaviour
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

My Manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.testes.activity.FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.testes.activity.SecondActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.testes.activity.FirstActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And this is all I need to have it working your way. I start my `FirstActivity`, click my Button to go to the `SecondActivity`, click the `ActionBar` home button and it goes back to `FirstActivity`.

Comment: Well, It didn't work as you said for me, but I solved the problem with calling the parentActivityName with the name of the current activity (and not the main one) , and it worked. Weird.

Comment: Are you sure it's not finishing the app, then restart it? You can't see the difference because you have no methods in your OnCreate.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. If it was finishing the app and restarting it I would get my Home screen for a while, and then see the FirstActivity. It is calling FirstActivity `onCreate()` again, but it is not finishing the app.